# taking and writing variables for a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Basically here's what I want:  A batch file that prompts the user to set a variable,

```
 set /p x=
```

then the batch file writes the variable to a file of some sort (abc.txt)  Then later on, in a different batch file, the program retrieves the variable from the text document, and sets it as %x% again for whatever use.  If there are any questions, or if I'm not clear enough, please comment, and I will revise.  thanks.

Comment: If you are only saving one value then write it with `set /p x=&echo %x%>abc.txt` and read it with `set /p x=<abc.txt&echo %x%` but if you have more than one value you will need to read it with a for/f command

Comment: Thank you, but I am afraid I am unfamiliar with the for command.  Would you mind clearing that up a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Batch Files, you can redirect input and ouput using `<` and `>` respectively.

#### Input.bat

```
@echo off
:: Take input and set value to x
set /p "x=: "
:: Print out the value of x to the screen, but redirect this to a text file
Echo %x% >> abc.txt
Echo EOF & Pause & Exit
```

#### Read.bat

```
@echo off
:: Set x to the first line in abc.txt
set /p x=< abc.txt
Echo First Line of abc.txt: %x%
Echo.
:: Set x to last line in abc.txt, incase it is multi-line file
for /f "delims=" %%a in (abc.txt) do (set x=%%a)
Echo Last Line of abc.txt: %x%
Echo.
Echo EOF & Pause & Exit
```

That should help you understand.

Mona.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that works best for me.

So I have the variable %x%, right?  I got it from this:

```
set /p x=
```

then I write a mini-batch file.

```
echo set y=%x% >> abc.bat
```

then later on in a different script, I can use

```
call abc.bat
```

the variable y will be the value that I had in the origional batch script.